# ExtJS and grails

Tags: grails

Does someone have any examples for using ExtJS (3.0) as frontend with grails, e.g. reading grid data with JSON, error handling with JsonReader, etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942847/experience-using-extjs-with-grails/943633#943633

Comment: Thank you for the link.

There you mention some example code. Is it possible to get this code?

Thanks.

Regards
Gerhard Pachler

Answer (score 0):

Searching over google i found [tutorials](http://grails.org/Using+ExtJS+Layouts+with+Grails+Layouts) in grails site. Moreover , some other example is :

[example one](http://compiledammit.com/2012/08/20/simple-grails-extjs-coffeescript-example/)
[example two](http://myxaab.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/customizing-spring-security-login-using-extjs-in-grails-apps/)

Apart from it , there is a similar question [hear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316129/looking-for-a-sample-application-with-extjs-grails)