# Looking for a sample application with ExtJS + Grails

Tags: grails, extjs, open-source

Although I prefer libraries that are open source, ExtJS has really nice set of widgets that could save me tons of time. So I am leaning towards using ExtJS for the view. However, when I did the search on the web trying to find a sample application that can get me started quickly, I didn't find one. I wonder if this means ExtJS + Grails is not that popular in the Grails world, or am I missing something?

Comment: ExtJS sure is open source. However, its license (GPL) makes it difficult to use with other frameworks. However, Grails (Apache License) should be no problemn.

Answer (score 4):

I did a Google got few (One example from grails site itself). Have a look at these links:

- http://www.reverttoconsole.com/blog/codesnippets/dirt-simple-extjs-grid-on-grails/
- http://grails.org/Using+ExtJS+Layouts+with+Grails+Layouts

These forum and stackoverflow posts may be helpful:

- [Experience using extjs with grails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942847/experience-using-extjs-with-grails/)
- http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?54153-integrate-Extjs-with-grails

Finally, I don't think ExtJs is not popular with Grails world. You should understand that ExtJs is client side technology, so it will work with any server side. Most of your data exchange will happen using JSON or XML.

Answer (score -1):

Did you have too much investment in Grails?

Because I'm happy using ExtJS front end backedup with JAX-RX + JPA 2.0 + EJB 3.1 + CDI + Google's GSON.

With standard Java EE 6 it's very easy to craft server code now.